# Jsp/MySQL- Storing output from SELECT query into a string?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

This is my select query

```
("SELECT firstName FROM user WHERE username = username;")
```

How do I store this into a string variable, so I can output it on my jsp page?

EDIT: Code that I ran

```
string firstname;

try{  


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contacts","root","root"); 


Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT firstName FROM user WHERE username = username;");



while(rs.next())  {
fname=new String(rs.getString(1));
System.out.println("First Name:"+firstname);  
con.close();  
   }
}
catch(Exception e){ 
  System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Comment: Show us the code you wrote that executes the query and iterates over the result set, and explain what is confusing about storing the results in a string.

Comment: @Jim Garrison I edited the code into my original post

Comment: I tried removiing "con.close()" and now I'm getting the last value stored under the column "Firstname" in my table- Is there something wrong with my select query? I know my cookie for the userName is passing in the correct value, because I already outputted and checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is wrong, it's like `SELECT firstName FROM user`. You need to set `userName` as a parameter.

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT firstName FROM user WHERE username = ?;");  
stmt.setString(1, userName);

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();

if(rs.next())  {
    fname=new String(rs.getString(1));
    System.out.println("First Name:"+firstname);  
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm really new to MySQL, so I've been stuck on that for a while.